# Nginx plus as load balancer for AWS ECS Fargate Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, api-gateway, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

[image]I have an ALB that front ends my fargate instances / services. I have a requirement to migrate an NGINX plus api gateway to front end the fargate services. Which means i would want to do away with my ALB. Is there any documentation around how to deploy nginx plus to front end fargate services. I am not able to find any online. Also i would want to do away with ALB because that would be redundant . If you need any more information please let me know .

I asked nginx team for documentation and they said it is part of professional services which is wierd as i am only asking for documentation.

The ALB / App Mesh might serve what i need but i do not want to go that route since i have my nginx plus server pre built and ready to go .

Best
Viswanath Sekar

Comment: can you upload a diagram like that https://cacoo.com/assets/site/img/examples/aws-hero-left.png to understand your requirement ?

Comment: Done pleas check

Comment: before answer you, why nginx + and no an ALB ??? I think ALB is more less cost vs nginx plus, and the ALB is more efficient

Comment: i have some specific requirements for cache , cookie (open close ) and other service discovery piece that alb does not provide and need to bring in service mesh etc to deal with it. nginx plus provides some of this out of the box

Comment: Ok will answer now...

Comment: Apparently nginx team mentioned it works with fargate but the documentation of that is professional services ? Really ?

Comment: Maybe not... you need to scale horizontally or have a static quantity of containers in fargate?